# how does this code work when adding an event to a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm confused by the code in the `if (obj.attachEvent) {...}` block. I found this example while looking at this page: http://codebits.glennjones.net/cheatsheet/javascript.htm#events

Anyway, can someone explain what the code is doing? I'm assuming that `obj` is a DOM element, `type` is the type of event (like `click` or `hover`), and `fn` is the callback function.

```
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj) {
        if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj['e' + type + fn] = fn;
            obj[type + fn] = function () { obj['e' + type + fn](window.event); };
            obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fn]);
        } else {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        }
    }
};
```

I always use the following code to do cross-browser event attachment (without jQuery). Is the above approach in any way better than what I do?

```
function attachEvent(element, type, fn) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + type, fn);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know `attachEvent` is the function in Explorer and I am not sure what will `this` refer to when the function is invoked  if we add listener like this. Needs to test this.

```
`element.attachEvent('on' + type, fn);`
```

But this code

```
 obj['e' + type + fn] = fn;  // adds listener as a function of the object obj
 obj[type + fn] = function () { obj['e' + type + fn](window.event); };  // creates a proxy function which invokes the listener.
 obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fn]);  // adds proxy function as listener
```

adds one function to the object and calls the original listener function from  that function. This ensures that inside the original listener function `this` will refer to the object for which listener has been added. This is actually for old versions of explorer I think.

Comment: interesting... I think that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Commented in code below:

```
if (obj.attachEvent) {  //if the browser supports the attachEvent method
    obj['e' + type + fn] = fn; //store the handler
    obj[type + fn] = function () { obj['e' + type + fn](window.event); }; //create the callback that invokes the handler stored above
    obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fn]); //Attach an event handler to the on<event>, such as onclick
} else {
    obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false); //otherwise, default to browsers supporting addEventListener
}
```

Comment: how does `obj['e' + type + fn]` work though? `type` is a string... `fn` is a function... how does this indexing work?

Comment: It could implicitly call toString() to perform a conversion to string... I'm not 100% sure if it does that.